# views and views data export (a question about drupal scaling)

Tags: 7

our drupal site has ~ 6 million nodes.

I have a view, which i want to add the possibility to also export the total results in csv format.

imagine a vie may return as many as 500 k nodes - results.

My question is if i add this option also, to our drupal site, is there a chance that our site's performance will degrade?

I am using export in batches, and i have set this number to 50, in order to avoid timeouts.

Finally, is there any chance our site someday will stall?

I mean say we have around 500 users online, using views all the time, what are the risks, and the overhead to each new view i add?

I would appreciate a thorough explanation of your experience with the scaling of drupal 7 and mysql which is what we have

Comment: I'm sorry, but these are impossible questions to answer. There are way too many variables: the number and type of relationships (joins) in each view, how dynamic or cacheable the data is, how tables are indexed in relation to the views queries, the other modules that are installed, etc (a whole lot of etc). Infrastructure: number and types of servers (application, database, caching, etc), the physical characteristics of each server, how each service on the servers is configured, etc (a whole lot of etc). MySQL: there are literally dozens of books about tuning and scaling MySQL.

Comment: Disclaimer: I am the content author of website mentioned in my profile, Network profile that includes downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning, FAQ and contact info.  Please make contact to review your situation.